# How to get to get the value of @@identity or SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() from stored procedure in C# code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, identity, sqlcommand

I use SQL Server 2012. In this stored procedure, I want to get the value of `@@identity` or `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. `intMyIdentity` is the identity column.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [spMyInsert] 
    (@vchVar AS VARCHAR(20), 
     @fltVar AS FLOAT)
AS
    SELECT TOP 1 intMyIdentity 
    FROM MyTbl  
    WHERE vchVar = @vchVar

    IF @@rowcount = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO MyTbl (vchVar, fltVar) 
        VALUES (@vchVar, @fltVar)

        SELECT @@identity AS intMyIdentity 
        -- SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
```

How can I get the value of `@@identity` or `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in C# ?

When using `ExecuteScalar`, it returns 0, instead of the correct value.

```
SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
oConn.Open();

mCommand.CommandText = "spMyInsert";
mCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vchVar", txtMyVar.Text));
mCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fltVar", dblMyVar));
mCommand.Connection = oConn;
mCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 

intMyIdentity = Convert.ToInt32(mCommand.ExecuteScalar());  --> this always return 0
oConn.Close();
```

Edited: this query works

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTbl WHERE vchVar = @vchVar)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO myTbl (vchVar, fltVar)
    VALUES (@vchVar, @fltVar)

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

Comment: [mCommand.ExecuteReader()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.8): `using (var reader = mCommand.ExecuteReader()) { while (reader.Read()) { ... } }`. There will be many examples on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You will always get the result of the first `SELECT` statement you execute this way, because it produces a result set. Fold the check into the statement with `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTbl WHERE vchVar = @vchVar)`; this also fixes a hole with concurrent inserts.

Answer (score -3):

When you use ExecuteScalar, your stored procedure must RETURN the @@identity. Something like RETURN @@IDENTITY;

Comment: First, `ExecuteScalar` does not access the return value but the first column of the first row. Getting the return value means allocating a parameter for it, which is actually more convoluted. Second, a stored procedure's return value can only be a single `INT` -- which works fine until you have a table with a `BIGINT` identity, so not a very future-proof solution.

Comment: ExecuteReader returns nothing in reader.Read: SqlDataReader reader = mCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())  //-->it doesn't go to this while loop
{
 ..
}

Comment: I changed the stored procedure to RETURN @@IDENTITY or RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY(), and intMyIdentity still returns 0

Comment: Based on Jeroen Mostert's idea, I updated the query to use "IF NOT EXISTS", and that works. I have updated the original posting with the fix. THank you